# multiprocessing- how to load the data only once in the working memory

Tags: python, web-scraping, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code. I want to load the data once in memory and then run the function get_ids in parallel. Actually, the data was loading 8 times. What follows in a memory error. Also, I'm very happy over hints to optimize the multiprocessing.

I use python 3.8
With windows and 16 GB ram and 8 CPU

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import json
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import re
import time
NUM_CPUS = mp.cpu_count()
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\final_tweets_de')
    
directory =r'C:\Users\final_tweets_de'
path= r'C:\Users\final_tweets_de'

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    fh = open(os.path.join(path, file),'r')
    if file =="SARS_CoV.json":
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
            data_tweets = json.load(json_file)
    
def get_id(data_tweets):
    for i in range(0,len(data_tweets)):
        try:
            account = data_tweets[i]['user_screen_name']
            created = datetime.datetime.strptime(data_tweets[i]['date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            until = created + relativedelta(days=10)
            id = data_tweets[i]['id']
            filename = re.search(r'(.*).json',file).group(1) + '_' + 'tweet_id_' +str(id)+ '_' + 'user_id_' + str(data_tweets[i]['user_id'])
            
            try:
                os.system('snscrape twitter-search "(to:'+account+') since:'+created.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+' until:'+until.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+' filter:replies" >C:\\Users\\Antworten\\antworten_SARS_CoV.json\\'+filename)
            except:
                continue
        except:
            Exception:logging.exception("f(%r) failed" % (args,))
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
     pool = mp.Pool(NUM_CPUS)
     get_id(data_tweets)
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
```

## Update

After the comment from @tdelaney, I split the data into smaller pieces and have no memory errors yet. But now, the cores are still not fully used. I have a workload of around 20 percent.

Comment: Everything at module level is reexecuted for each worker in the multiprocessing pool. This will be challenging because on Windows, child processes don't share memory with the parent.

Comment: Thanks, If I use a loop to load the data in small pieces I should be able to avoid this problem? If multiprocessing would then automatically divide the steps of the loop between the cores? Does this problem also exist with linux?